# flex-flow column with side by side divs in body

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Trying to do a column flexbox with header, body and footer and then within the body have 2 divs side by side that respect the boundaries of the flex-box (ie, don't overflow the footer).

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: blue;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0 1 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 225px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Simple test case in jsfiddle

```
<div class='app'>
  <div class='header'>
    <p><b>header</b>
      <br />
      <br />(sized to content)</p>
  </div>
  <div class='body'>
    <div class='inner'>

      <div class='left'>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
        <p>test 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class='right'>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
        <p>test 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class='footer'>
    <p><b>footer</b> (fixed height)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/XJ45G19/9e7vjykv/

[image]

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you exact issue is, but what is wrong with it when you remove `position: absolute` from `.inner`?

Comment: arg! Thanks Joe. I feel dumb. If you want to post that answer, I'll be happy to accept it. and thanks again for your help.

Comment: Haha, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting per request as answered:

Remove `position: absolute` from `.inner`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overflow in the middle `.body` element because the content has been absolutely positioned, which removes it from the normal flow.

Once you remove `position: absolute` from `.inner`, the content takes up space, and the vertical scrollbar pops up on `.body`.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I would like to give Joe first shot at it but I do appreciate the response